# Django triple relation with select/prefetch related?

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def to_dict():
        prefs = self.prefs.get()
        return {'id': self.pk, 'birthday': prefs.birthday}

class UserPref(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, rel_class=models.OneToOneRel, related_name='prefs')
    birthday = models.DateTimeField()

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
    name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def to_dict():
        return {'name': self.name, 'owner': self.user.to_dict}
```

I need to get all the items for a user and also include user preferences in the response, like so:

```
items: [{
    name: 'item 1',
    owner: {
        id: 1,
        birthday: '11/11/1900'
    }
}]
```

My queryset is as follows:

```
items = Items.objects.all().select_related('user')
result = [item.to_dict for item in items]
```

The problem is that whenever item.to_dict is called, there's a query being done on the UserPref model because of this line `prefs = self.prefs.get()`

So if I have 20 items, there will be 21 queries instead of 1 with 2 joins.

How can I optimize this?

Note: using prefetch_related instead of select_related, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the prefetch_related option:

```
Items.objects.all().prefetch_related('user')
```

This should do two queries to the database and then do the join in python between the User and its items.